# How to access .net aspx page into BOT Framework V4 Adaptive Card

Tags: .net, web-applications, botframework, bots

I have an MS BOT Framework V4 chatbot.
I already have one other application that is hosted on the windows server and built using .net framework web application to raise a ticket.
Now I want to call that application page (.aspx) into BOT Adaptive Card.
Is it possible to do it in the current Adaptive Card?
Also if not, can you let me know an alternate way to achieve this.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Are you saying that you have an adaptive card that is shown to the user. Then that user uses the card, which in turn calls back to the bot, which then calls your 'other application'. And what you want to do in the end is update the adaptive card with the new information?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your question, but... If you are thinking in embed your web in adaptive card not is possible. But you have another options.

- You can redirect to another web (yours) when you will click button. This option open the web in other browser.
- Make an adaptive card with your ticket fields and send it all to your API or DB (Also you can asking field by field in the conversation flow).

The important point to work with adaptive cards is this web :  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/

Both options are on the samples